# How to add unique Custom Metrics hits on Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, session-cookies, google-tag-manager

Consider a web application with different pages:

Page 1 has links that lead to Page 2. Page 2 has links that lead to Page 3 and so on. Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

- Add +1 to a `Unique Page 1 Views` Custom Metric, each time a **unique
  user** is visiting Page 1.
- Add +1 to a `Unique Page 1 Clicks` Custom
  Metric, each time a user is clicking on a link. However, I only want to count **unique link clicks** from each user (only increment custom metric by 1 per user/session).

I want to do the same for Page 2, 3, and so on.

The solution I came up with is using Javascript to place a session cookie on the visitor's browser. Since I'm using Google Tag Manager, I'm firing this script before anything else (priority is set to 9999) and set + return the cookie's value as the Custom Metric's value.

If the cookie exists, I'm returning 0, if it doesn't I'm returning 1 for the custom metric. I'm running this script each time when the page loads or before the user clicks on the link, so the cookie gets updated.

```
function setCookie(name, value) {
  document.cookie = name + '=' + value;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
  var cookie = [];
  var name = cname + "=";
  var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
  var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
  for(var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
      c = c.substring(1);
    }
    if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
      cks.push(c.substring(name.length, c.length));
    }
  }
  
  if (cookie.length < 1) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return cookie; 
  }
}
  
function checkCookie(cname) {
  var nMetric = cname + 'MetricValue';
  var nPath = cname + 'Path';
  var path = window.location.origin + window.location.pathname;
  
  var ck = getCookie(nMetric);
  
  if (ck === false) {
    setCookie(nMetric, 1);
    setCookie(nPath, path);
    // console.log('No cookie set. Adding metric: 1. Path: ' + path);
    return;
  }
  
  var ck2 = getCookie(nPath);

  if (ck2 !== false && ck2.indexOf(path) > -1) {
    setCookie(nMetric, 0);
    // console.log('Cookie already exists based on path. Adding metric: 0. Path: ' + path);
  } else {
    setCookie(nMetric, 1);
    setCookie(nPath, path);
    // console.log('No cookie set. Based on Path check. Adding metric: 1, Setting path to: ' + path); 
  } 
  return;
}

checkCookie('uniquePageClick');
```

This script is being fired just before the user's click is being sent as a Metric. I have the same code for the Page Views too which is fired with first priority with the GA Pageload trigger.

I have tested this setup with Google Tag Manager's `preview mode` and it seems to be working perfectly. I also checked that the tag is firing before anything else + changing the Metric's value as expected. However, there are some discrepancies in the real-time tests I've done.

There are times when I can see higher unique Click Counts than Page Views, which suggests, that some visitors' clicks are being recorded multiple times. I have also tested if I'm loading the page 2 times very quickly, it sometimes gives me 2 Pageviews instead of 1.

I am assuming that this is related to the speed at which the cookie is being set/updated/retrieved. I also tried setting up the cookie so that it doesn't expire until a few days, but I still get the same results.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there something I could do about this either in Javascript, Tag Manager, or on Google Analytics? Could it be a race condition? If so, what are the steps to stop this from happening?

Comment: Can't you achieve what you're trying to do by looking at the already existing "unique pageviews" metric and the "unique events" metric?

Comment: @XTOTHEL Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately not, because I need to access this information for each Page in one table. Which is the main reason why I created custom metrics.

Comment: Something like this? https://imgur.com/a/Au62DbQ

Comment: @XTOTHEL I want the Page 1, Page 2, Page 3, etc metrics to be the columns and the dimensions to be the like "campaign", "source", "keyword". This is why I came up with the idea of Custom Metrics.

Comment: You can bring in "campaign, source, medium, keyword, etc' as part of the column. So essentially you should be able to see the campaign that drove traffic to what page and how many unique pageviews and the unique events that's happened on that page, again broken down by campaign, source, medium, keyword, etc.

Comment: @XTOTHEL Hmmm, I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. This is basically what I want to achieve: https://i.imgur.com/3uK9VhL.png

Comment: I'm suggesting you could do this with existing GA data that's captured: https://imgur.com/a/DQdnCFu